# Flutter flavors

Tags: flutter, build, android-productflavors

I am developing a flutter app. I want to add two different flavors to separate out few functionalities specific to flavor. I have followed [this](https://medium.com/@angeloavv/easily-build-flavors-in-flutter-android-and-ios-with-flutter-flavorizr-d48cbf956e4) documentation. Here is my pubspec.yaml file.

```
name: flutter_app
version: 1.0.20+20

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.3.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  provider: ^4.0.1
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  intl: ^0.16.0
  shared_preferences:
  http: ^0.12.0+4
  sqflite: ^1.2.0
  path_provider:
  permission_handler: ^4.1.0
  package_info: ^0.4.0+18
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  #flutter_local_notifications: ^0.7.1+1
  #firebase_messaging: ^5.0.1+1
  #fluttertoast: ^3.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_flavorizr: ^1.0.7

flavorizr:
  app:
    android:
      flavorDimensions: "flavor-type"
    ios:

  flavors:
    mainapp:
      app:
        name: "Main App"

      android:
        applicationId: "com.example.app1"

      ios:
        bundleId: "com.example.app1"

    banana:
      master:
        name: "App Master"

      android:
        applicationId: "com.example.app2"
      ios:
        bundleId: "com.example.app2"

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/fonts/
    - assets/drawables/
    - assets/icon/
    - assets/lang/en.json
    - assets/lang/de.json
    - assets/lang/de-DE.json
    - assets/lang/de-CH.json
    - assets/lang/de-AT.json
    - assets/lang/en-IN.json

  fonts:
    - family: Poppins-Bold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf
    - family: Poppins-Medium
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf
```

After running **flutter pub run flutter_flavorizr**, i get the following error.

```
The following fields were missing: [app]. Read the docs for further details
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'flavorizr' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: flavorizr
       Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
       Processor._initAvailableProcessors (package:flutter_flavorizr/processors/processor.dart:110:18)
       new Processor (package:flutter_flavorizr/processors/processor.dart:88:5)
       execute (package:flutter_flavorizr/flutter_flavorizr.dart:52:25)
       main (file:///D:/Users/Dhaval/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_flavorizr-1.0.7/bin/flutter_flavorizr.dart:4:3)
       _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
       _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
pub finished with exit code 255
```

Am I missing out something ? How can I solve this issue ? Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.
Posting it in case this helps someone else.
I spent quite a bit of time looking around. The error messages are generic and cryptic and I could not find any leads.

So I reviewed their code. It turns out that the error message is not related to the issue. This error is thrown when the flavorizer block in my pubscpec.yaml was not correct. Once I reviewed the section and corrected the mistakes, the command worked.

Comment: I'm still having the issue. Do you have an idea on what else I could do?

Comment: It's been a while I worked on this, but paste the error message, and the block, and I will see if I can help.

Answer (score 1):

In my pubspec.yaml file, I had following configurations at the start of flavorizr

```
flavorizr:
  ide: "idea"
  app:
    android:
      flavorDimensions: "flavor-type"
    ios:
```

i removed the line

```
ios:
```

and the error was gone.